# I need to export sql server results to new excel work book?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I need results into a new workbook, at present am getting the results in existing workbook?

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rsstring As String
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\WorkbookName.xls"
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PRATEEP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=PPDS_20Dec_V1_Decomposition;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString
rsstring = "SELECT * FROM GE_PRODUCT_RESOURCE_MASTER;"
rs.Open rsstring, sConnString
 ActiveSheet.Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset rs 
rs.Close
conn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it and it worked fine. Anyway to make it bulletproof.

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rsstring As String
Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add 'To avoid ActiveWorkbook
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PRATEEP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=PPDS_20Dec_V1_Decomposition;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString
rsstring = "SELECT * FROM GE_PRODUCT_RESOURCE_MASTER;"
rs.Open rsstring, sConnString
NewWorkbook.Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset rs 'directly call the NewWorkbook
rs.Close
conn.Close
NewWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\WorkbookName.xls" 'Save after your change
End Sub
```

Comment: Still it is same, results are not grtting into new work

Comment: Does it still get in the existing workbook ? How is your workbook named and how should your new workbook be named ?

Comment: yes, my workbook named as 'mdmfinal'....new workbook can be anything...i just need results in new workbook !!!

Comment: There is no function, in your provided code block, which could save the result in your mdmfinal. Either it came from an old try or you have any other method which does it.

Comment: A idea came in my mind, eventually you dont have rights to save on C: try to write just the workbookname so it will be saved in the same folder as your master file is located. Still doesn´t explain why it gets saved in your master.